# Installing Titanium Studio on Windows 7 64bit machine

Tags: android, titanium

Can anybody please share any step by step guide to install and configure Titanium Studio (which version should I use ?) on a Windows 7 64 bit machine for Android development ?

I am trying the latest version but it seems not working. Can't set the andorid sdk path.

I have JDK 1.7 64 bit installed in my machine. I think 32 bit 1.6 is required but it was suppose to be managed by the installer ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a step by step guide with pictures in the documentation. I assume this is what you're looking for? http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Setting_up_Studio

Comment: Yeh its the official one and I have started with that and result is why I have raised this issue - Can you suggest based on what you have tried ?

Comment: I have only installed it on Ubuntu so I can't suggest anything that would help you. From a quick search I found [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXShVUwPzaQ) and [a blog entry](www.appliedclub.org/blog/2013/02/12/installing-titanium-appcelerator-on-windows) on how to install Titanium on W7

Comment: The blog link is broken and the video seems just straight forward way - nothing fancy is done.

Answer (score 0):

Check below links :

- http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/f07d923c-a281-3010-72bd-b7bb9dcd3ae2?overridelayout=true
- http://www.appliedclub.org/blog/2013/02/12/installing-titanium-appcelerator-on-windows/
- http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Setting_up_Studio
- http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Setting_up_the_Titanium_CLI

Steps you need to follow :

- Downloading and Installing Titanium Studio
- Launching Titanium Studio
- Configuring Titanium Studio
- Add path of default Android SDK
- Creating a project in Titanium Studio.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the documentation itself. The documentation specifically says that you need to use 32 bit java v1.6 regardless of your system configuration, you need to manually install 32 bit java, set the environment variables.

You may also refer

1. [Failed to Load JNI Shared Library When Trying to Use Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037022/failed-to-load-jni-shared-library-when-trying-to-use-titanium/17037236#17037236)
2. [how to install sdk Android with titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102573/how-to-install-sdk-android-with-titanium/23105953#23105953)
3. [Titanium 3.1.0 - Emulator process exited with code 1 - Can't compile APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066347/titanium-3-1-0-emulator-process-exited-with-code-1-cant-compile-apk/17205187#17205187)

Hope it helped you. Let me know if you have any queries

Comment: The document does say that 32 bit JDK version 1.6 is needed but din find any mentioning that I need to install it manually, instead it was suppose to install when the studio is being installed : Please check the link : http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Setting_up_Studio-section-37540095_SettingupStudio-OracleJDK

Comment: @marifrahman: However you need to install them manually. Titanium studio will not install java for you